# How to generate a valid sample token with stripe?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Currently I'm integrating [stripe](https://stripe.com/) payments into may django-based backed app - [here](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) is how it can be done with python. I've some integration tests done with `APIClient` and after payments were introduced I need to generate a sample token (normally received from client and generated with stripe.js) to make a successful payment.

Since these are integration tests I can't mock any part of my code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just create the token with [stripe.Token.create()](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=python#create_card_token):

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_asdfkljasblahblah123"

token = stripe.Token.create(
    card={
        "number": '4242424242424242',
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2016,
        "cvc": '123'
    },
)
```

To make a charge, only the `id` is required. This can be obtained with `token.id`, after the token has been generated.

Comment: It is very grateful when I find exactly what I'm looking for here in stack overflow.  In the first link!!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the [`stripecli`](https://github.com/stripe-contrib/stripe-cli) and do something like:

```
stripe card create \
--customer=some_customer_id \
--name=some_name \
--number=4242424242424242 \
--cvc=123 \
--exp-month=12 \
--exp-year=2020
```

Just make sure you have your [`~/.stripecli`](https://github.com/stripe-contrib/stripe-cli#configuration) setup otherwise you'll probably need to add the flag `--key=sk_test_123456789blabla`